# Error: Nock: No match for request - but request is correct

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, nock

I'm trying to write a mock test for the spotify web api authorize endpoint. I have the following code for nock:

```
nock("https://accounts.spotify.com/")
  .post("/api/token", {
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    code: "DummyAccessCode",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000"
  })
  .reply(201, {access_token: 12345, refresh_token: 67890, expires_in: 3600});
```

My request in order to get a mocked request is:

```
const res = await request("https://accounts.spotify.com")
  .post("/api/token")
  .send({
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    code: "DummyAccessCode",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000"
  })
```

I keep getting the error in the title once it hits the request and I don't know why. The request should match the nock but it isn't. Another detail to note is that when I run `console.log(nock.activeMocks());` it prints: 'POST [https://accounts.spotify.com:443/api/token'](https://accounts.spotify.com:443/api/token%27)
Which doesn't make sense to me because I never placed a 443 in the url. Really hoping someone can help me with this because I've been struggling with writing my tests for the past 2 weeks and finally made it to this stage of understanding. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @slideshowp2 I solved the error, see answer below. Was just fatigued and couldn't think straight, thank you for attempting to help me though, I appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To everyone I solved the error. It was just an issue with my URL for the nock that I passed in. It was missing a '/'.

Here's the code for future reference for anyone wondering:

```
it("/login should return access token, refresh token, and expiriation", async () => {
nock("https://accounts.spotify.com/", {
  reqheaders: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
  }
})
  .post("/api/token", {
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    code: "DummyAccessCode",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000"
  })
  .reply(201, {access_token: 12345, refresh_token: 67890, expires_in: 3600});
const res = await request("https://accounts.spotify.com")
  .post("/api/token")
  .send({
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    code: "DummyAccessCode",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000"
  })
  .expect(201);
```